# Intel graphics drivers APT repository using weak SHA-1 diget

Tags: apt, intel-graphics, gnupg

I have an `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` file with the line

```
deb https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main wily main #Intel Graphics drivers
```

Now, when I try to `apt-get upgrade`, I get a message saying:

```
W: GPG error: https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main wily InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2CC2A1B90A3B3268
```

Why is the repository not signed? What can I do about it?

Comment: [How to fix missing GPG keys?](/q/127326) has absolutely nothing to do with this question beyond being about Apt repository keys.